# In Rust, is there a way to use worker threads for managing 1000s of channels?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've looked at mpsc and crossbeam, and not finding what I'm looking for. For a given receiver, when it would normally block with a recv, instead I'd like it to park. Later, when a message arrives, I'd like it to unpark and process the received message. There could be 1000s of channels, so having a thread per-channel doesn't work. Instead, I'd want to have a couple of worker threads which manage the 1000s of channels.

Answer (score 0):

[crossbeam::channel::Select](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.3/crossbeam/channel/struct.Select.html) is what you're looking for.

Alternatively, using an evented runtime (tokio or whatnot).